# What is the Computational Complexity of Minimising a Linear Function over a General Convex Set?

Tags: convex-optimization, computational-complexity

Is the computational complexity of finding or approximating $\inf\{c^Tx:x\in X\}$ (where $X$ is a compact convex given explicitly or by some reasonable oracle) known?

EDIT: Suppose we had an efficient separation oracle. Would I be correct in saying that for $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the runtime would be $\tilde O(n^6\log n)$, where the tilde notation suppresses log-dependence on the data, and also suppresses the runtime of the oracle?

Comment: In my view this is way too broad. You're getting somewhere by specifying that there could be an oracle, but what kind of information would that oracle provide? And in what way are existing online resources insufficient here?

Comment: Well by all means, please edit your question to bring in as much detail as possible.